# SQL query involving NULL values

Tags: sql, database, null

The following are the tables I am working with:

- **Movie** (`mID, title, year, director`)
- **Reviewer** (`rID, name`)
- **Rating** (`rID, mID, stars, ratingDate`)

Which statement would I use to display all reviewers that have a `NULL` value for the date (`ratingDate`) meaning  I need to extract information from both the `Reviewer` and `Rating` table.

I have tried different things with the `IS NULL` command but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: isnt this a assignment of db-class.org by stanford ?

Comment: Hm, is this for class?  If so, marking it as homework is appreciated.

Comment: @Phoenix Yep, question 4! haha. "I have tried different things with the IS NULL command but to no avail." What have you tried ? Because `IS NULL` is the way to go. By the way a quick google search got me the whole solution to your set of problems. Look around.

Comment: I have tried: SELECT name FROM Reviewer WHERE ratingDate IS NULL

Comment: @batsta13 The `Reviewer` table does not have a `ratingDate` column so that's why it won't work. The answer is already given below, but you should look into the basics of joining tables and maybe using subqueries.

Comment: quite right I am new to SQL am just trying to understand the basics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Reviewer.name 
FROM Reviewer
INNER JOIN Rating
ON Reviewer.rID = Rating.rID
WHERE Rating.ratingDate IS NULL
```

Try this, I think it will do.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    rev.rID
  , rev.name
  , rat.mID
  , rat.stars
FROM 
      Reviewer AS rev
  JOIN
      Rating AS rat
    ON rat.rID = rev.rID
WHERE
    rat.ratingDate IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be trivial

```
select *
from rating
join reviewer on rating.rid = reviewer.rid
join movie on rating.mid = movie.mid
where ratingdate is null
```

so there might be other problems - e.g. the ratingdate is not a date and not null but an empty string (`ratingdate = ''`)?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a [`LEFT JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join). That is, a `JOIN` that includes null values on one side.